# SwiftUI double navigation bar

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having trouble with navigation in SwiftUI. I have a button on a navigation bar, if clicked it pushes a new navigation view with list of items. When one of those items is tapped, it pushes a detail view.

But I am ending up with something like this.
[image]

Below is the code

```
struct FirstView: View {

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List {
            ...
           }
           .navigationBarTitle(Text("First View"))
           .navigationBarItems(trailing: MyButton())
       }
    }
}

struct MyButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("SecondView", destination: SecondView())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           Text("My View")
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Remove the `NavigationView` from `SecondView`.

The `NavigationLink` puts the second view inside the first views navigations view, so you do not need to put it inside a second one.

You can still update the title of the view from `SecondView` like so:

```
struct SecondView: View {
   var body: some View {
       Text("My View")
       .navigationBarTitle("Second View")
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Been trying to figure that one out! Thanks

Comment: Thanks you just saved me:->

Answer (score 3):

Quinn is right.
but if You don't want a big area above:

[image]

[image]

add:

```
struct SecondView: View {
   var body: some View {
       Text("My View")
        .navigationBarTitle("Second View", displayMode: .inline)
   }
}
```

Comment: This has been deprecated in favor of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitledisplaymode(_:)