# Saving image from imagepicker into a different view controller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to push a `UIImagePickerViewController` with a button in my parent view controller, but I want to display the image in a different view, not the parent view. I've tried

1. Pushing a new view and calling the image picker from a button there. However, because I have this view embedded inside a navigation view, I have a problem of [2 navigation bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065081/swiftui-double-navigation-bar). I can't hide navigation bar because then, I can't go back to the parent view.
2. Pushing a new view and calling the image picker directly (with no button). However, the image picker is not closing on its own and I can't go back to my parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

1. Have an observed object to be the main object (your `enviornmentObject`).
2. Add a `UIImage` property to it or any property you want to share between views (after all that's the job of an `environmentObject`
3. Share the enviornmentObject

This is your class

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedImage: UIImage? = nil // default it to nil in case nothing is selected
}
```

This is your main view

```
struct ContentView: View {
      @EnviornmentObject var appState: AppState
      @State var presentModal: Bool = false
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
                // Image can now easily be accessed by calling self.appState.selectedImage in any view that has @EnviornmentObject var appState: AppState
                if(self.appState.selectedImage != nil) {
                      Image(uiImage: self.appState.selectedImage!)
                } else {
                      // Image doesn't exist, add a placeholder
                      Text("No image selected")
                }

                Button("Show Modal") {
                      self.presentModal.toggle()
                }
          }.sheet(isPresented: self.$presentModal) {
               ModalView(presentModal: self.$presentModal)
          }
      }
}
```

// Your ImagePicker view or any other view that will change the selected Image

```
struct ModalView: View {
      @EnviornmentObject var appState: AppState
      @Binding var presentModal: Bool = false
      
      var body: some View {
          // Your logic to pick image goes here, I will simulate a button click
          Button("I will set an image") {
                self.appState.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "test.jpg")
                self.presentModal.toggle()
          }
      }
}
```

**In your `SceneDelegate` (VERY IMPORTANT)**

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.

        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(AppState()) // <- The important part
        
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Your modal view (or your image picker view, really anything)

**EDIT: I agree it should be presented as a modal; however, it is not 100% necessary. Presenting it as a modal or not this should work though.**

Answer (score 0):

As the docs for [UIUmagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) will tell you, it must be presented modally, not pushed. You are also responsible for dismissing it via the delegate.